# Is there analog of ".." for c++ namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Hello I have the following structure in my code:

```
namespace ns
{
class A
{
  public:
    class Impl
    {
        public: static int x;
    };
    class B
    {
      public:
        class Impl
        {
          public:
            Impl(){printf("%d", ns::A::Impl::x);}
        };
    };
};
}
```

Is there a way to access that x property, using a relative, not the absolute path?

It would be more convenient, because, someday I could change the namespace name from `ns` to e.g. `other`, or put this entire file into some outer namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent of "..", i.e. a way to specify "the enclosing namespace/class", but you can manually implement a similar thing:

```
class B
{
    typedef A parent;          // <---- add this

// ...

    printf("%d", parent::Impl::x);
```

In this particular situation it doesn't gain anything: this is just a more roundabout way of having `A::Impl::x` as Maxim suggested. But in general, if you have a more complicated hierarchy then this form may gain you some readability.

Comment: No.  Maxim's answer doesn't use a relative path, it goes forwards from the last common point in the hierarchy.

Comment: @JBentley in this case yes, just going `A::Impl::x` is the simplest solution. Updated my answer to clarify

Comment: That sounds like perhaps just a terminology issue. Maxim's answer is not a fully qualified name, which is what the OP wants, in order to solve his problem. It is "relative" to the set of names which are available in the current scope.

Comment: @JBentley I'm assuming that by "relative name" he means as he has suggested in the title of the post, like `..` can be used to mean "the parent directory, even if I don't know its name" in a filesystem.  Filesystem lookup doesn't quite work like namespace lookup though so it is not a great analogy.

Comment: @Matt McNabb, Why do you think the analogy is not good? The only difference i see are `.` and `..` "links".

Comment: @Necto there's no filesystem equivalent of `A::impl::x`. You either have to go down from `/`, or up or down one level from `.` . It doesn't work to do `cd /path/to/foo/bar/baz;  foo/quux/quum; ` if `quux` is a subdir of `foo` etc.

Comment: In C++ when you write `A::impl::x` it tries to resolve that in the current namespace; and if that fails it goes up one level and tries to resolve it, etc.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Not exactly. The scope search stops once the symbol is found. This is why `Impl::x` fails in the scope of `B::Impl` - it finds `B::Impl` and does not bother to consider `A::Impl` one scope up.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to access that x property, using a relative, not the absolute path?

Symbols from the enclosing scope/namespace are accessible in the current scope/namespace.

`ns::A::Impl::x` could be shortened to `A::Impl::x` (can't omit `A::` because you have two `Impl`).

Comment: Thank you. I tried smth like this, but it didn't work first time. Now I tried again, and it worked. //edited